# Unable to update mongoose Schema's validations

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am quiet new to mongoose, So i created a user model like this

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { 
        type: String,
        lowercase:true,
        unique:true
    },
    phone: {
        type:String,
        unique:true,
        sparse:true,
        required:true
    }});
mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);
```

I created this model, but later on i thought that name field should not be unique so i updated my model by removing unique attribute from name field. 
but is mongoose keeping some cache or something because even after updating the code in my model file when i do a user register request i am getting this error that duplicate key for name field and it is not accepting same names for 2 documents.

this is the error i am recieving :

> { [MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: kiotapp.users
>   index: name_1 dup key: { : "arihant daga 5" }]   name: 'MongoError',
>   message: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: kiotapp.users index:
>   name_1 dup key: { : "arihant daga 5" }',

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337388/mongodb-remove-unique-constraint

Comment: Thank you @hyades it worked fine with db.collections.dropIndexes() but now i ran into another problem, if i drop these indexes and later on when i try to set unique attribute again, mongoose is not creating indexes again automatically. can u help with that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.dropIndex()
```

refer : [https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/remove-indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/remove-indexes/)/